# High Sierra contacts disappear immediately after creation

Tags: icloud, contacts, gmail

I add a contact (Firstname, Lastname, Phone, Email) and save it.

After a few seconds, presumably when macOS tries to sync it to Gmail and/or iCloud, it disappears.

I have a Gmail account and an iCloud account synced, when I add the contact via the Android app, it stays in the Gmail address book and it gets synced into macOS.

At first it seemed to work again, when I disabled the iCloud Account. But: I now try to add a new contact and while typing in the contact details, the editor window simply disappears.

What can I do do make macOS contacts work again?

macOS High Sierra 10.13.2 (17C88)

Answer (score 2):

**Solved**

Someone in the Apple community gave solved my problem,
 many thanks (https://discussions.apple.com/message/32765319):

*Might be a corrupt .plist.*

*Do a backup, preferably 2 backups on 2 separate drives.*

*Quit the application.*

*Go to Finder and select your user/home folder. With that Finder window as the front window, either select Finder/View/Show View options or go command - J.  When the View options opens, check ’Show Library Folder’. That should make your user library folder visible in your user/home folder.  Select Library. Then go to Preferences/com.apple.AddressBook.plist.  Move the .plist to your desktop.*

*Restart the computer, open the application, and test. If it works okay, delete the plist from the desktop.*

*If the application is the same, return the .plist to where you got it from, overwriting the newer one.*

Comment: Thanks a lot! It happened to me for ages and still on Monterey. Before moving /Users/<my account>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.AddressBook.plist to Desktop I did stop Contacts and started it right afterwards. No restart of computer necessary, works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but on Mojave I'm having it happen, and not having the time right now to do the corrupt plist fix (safely with backups and all), if I create the new contact from within a group (rather than just in All Contacts) it does get created and saved. And yes, then found in All Contacts.
A workaround if someone bumps into this and doesn't want to chase the full repair right away...